# Adobe_Animate module does not initialize properly with requirejs

Tags: javascript, requirejs, adobe-animate

The self invoking module exported by Adobe_Animate does not initialize properly with requirejs. The module (Test.js) looks like this:

> (function (cjs, an) {
>
> var p; // shortcut to reference prototypes var lib={};var ss={};var
>   img={}; lib.ssMetadata = [];
>
> // symbols:
>
> // stage content: (lib.Untitled1 = function(mode,startPosition,loop) {
>     this.initialize(mode,startPosition,loop,{});
>
> // Layer_1  this.shape = new cjs.Shape();
>     this.shape.graphics.f().s("rgba(0,0,0,0.498)").ss(23.2,1,1).p("AluoHQlRT1R6kY");
>     this.shape.setTransform(89.7,133);
>
> this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this.shape).wait(1));
>
> }).prototype = p = new cjs.MovieClip(); p.nominalBounds = new
>   cjs.Rectangle(133.8,193.4,111.9,127.3); // library properties:
>   lib.properties = {    id: 'E010D875D1E4F54FAE30E27157A43177',     width:
>   200,  height: 248,    fps: 24,    color: "#BB0909",   opacity: 1.00,
>     manifest: [],   preloads: [] };

.....

> an.getComposition = function(id) {
>     return an.compositions[id]; }
>
> })(createjs = createjs||{}, AdobeAn = AdobeAn||{}); var createjs,
>   AdobeAn;

My config:

```
require.config({
        shim: {
            easel: {
                exports: 'createjs'
            },

            testjs: {
                deps: ['createjs'],
                exports: 'testjs'
            }
        },
        paths: {
            easel: 'libs/easeljs.min',
            test: "Test"

        }
    });
```

I have tested that createjs gets loaded, but probably too late. The errors I get are: *cjs.MovieClip is not a constructor* . The same error as I get if I load Test.js **before** createjs.js in a html file, like so:

```
<script src="Test.js"></script> 
<script src="libs/createjs.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like I got it working - without knowing exactly how. But, it seems in my setup the *require.config* has no effect. Even after commenting out the whole *require.config*, it still works!

Comment: Correction: it works most of the time. About 1 in 5 time it fails. This happens with and without the require.config.